# Biochemical conversion of ethanol to acetic acid

Tags: reaction-mechanism, redox, biochemistry

I have questions about the involvement of the electron transport chain (ETC) in the biochemical conversion of ethanol to acetic acid. In which of the reaction steps is the ETC employed?

Comment: I just made a question from your water comment..    as it merits a separate question  http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69388/in-the-production-of-vinegar-where-does-water-come-from     Hopefully somebody here will know/post an  answer.  You can comment on it if you want, though i'm not sure if 16 points will be enough rep to, but if not and you want to comment then you could do so here as it doesn't require much rep to comment on your question or an answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The principal conversion of ethanol to acetaldehyde takes place in the cytosol of liver cells, no ETC involved directly. This is mediated by the enzyme alcohol dehydrogenase (ADH). However, the NADH produced as a consequence would indeed deliver its electrons to the ETS, an electron transport chain.

The acetaldehyde is then metabolized to acetate in the mitochondria. Again, the involvement of the ETS is in accepting electrons from the NADH that is also produced in this step.

Here's the details: https://pubs.niaaa.nih.gov/publications/arh294/245-255.htm

Comment: Also further, acetate can react with Co-enzyme A to form acetyl coenzyme A. Which is used in a reaction with oxaloacetate to form citrate. Coenzyme A will form a thioester bond and can later be used in a reaction in conjunction with NAD+ and alpha-ketoglutarate to form succinyl-CoA and NADH.

Comment: @Bob. True. I limited my response to the OP's purview.

Comment: Of course! I just thought I'd add a little extra since I personally would have also been curious about where the carbon goes.

Comment: Many thanks guys for the input. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Also There's a water molecule in the second reaction where acetaldehyde goes to form acetate. Where does this water come from as it is not produced in the first step.

Comment: Also I notice that link mentions the liver, i.e. human cells doing it. And human cells of course have mitochondria which have an electron transport chain. But does this answer cover the case of for example, the conversion of alcohol that is done in the production of vinegar,  where the conversion is done by the bacteria Acetobacter aceti?

Comment: @Lobell this may help http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69388/in-the-production-of-vinegar-where-does-water-come-from

Comment: @Lobell. The water is abundant in the aqueous solutions these reactions occur in.